# Does independence between a random variable and a random vector imply independence between the random variable and the vector element?

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose I have $X$, a scalar random variable, independent of a random vector $(Y,Z)$. Does this imply that $X$ is independent of $Y$ and $Z$ individually?

My intuition is that yes, because if not, information about the random vector would tell us something about the random variable $X$, making it impossible for the variable and the vector to be independent of each other. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes. Actually independence is a matter of $\sigma$-algebras. $X$ and $(Y,Z)$ are independent iff $P(A\cap B)=P(A)×P(B)$ for every $A\in\sigma(X)$ and $B\in\sigma(Y,Z)$. Here evidently $\sigma(Y)\subseteq\sigma(Y,Z)$ and $\sigma(Z)\subseteq\sigma(Y,Z)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Measurable functions of independent random variables are independent. Hence $f(X) = X$ and $g(Y, Z) = Y$ are independent.

For proof, suppose $X$ is a random variable with values in a measurable space $(E, \mathcal{E})$ and $W$ is a random variable with values in a measurable space $(E', \mathcal{E}')$. Suppose $X$ and $W$ are independent. Then if $f$, $g$ are measurable functions for which $f(X)$ and $g(W)$ make sense, then for any measurable sets $A, B$,
\begin{align}
P(f(X) \in A, g(W) \in B) &= P(X \in f^{-1}(A), W \in g^{-1}(B)) \\
&= P(X \in f^{-1}(A))P(W \in g^{-1}(B)) \\
&= P(f(X) \in A)P(g(W) \in B).
\end{align}
Hence $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are independent.

In your case, we let $W = (Y, Z)$ and $(E, \mathcal{E}) = (\mathbb{R}, B(\mathbb{R}))$ and $(E', \mathcal{E}') = (\mathbb{R}^2, B(\mathbb{R}^2))$. We use $f(x) = x$, and $g(y, z) = y$. The above theorem gives that $f(X) = X$ and $g(Y, Z) = Y$ are independent.